# Gulp - one stream splits into multiple threads

Tags: gulp

I'm need implement that gulp task, where stream splits into multiple threads.

```
                        gulp.src("./src/index.coffee")
                                      |
                                      |
                                      V
                               .pipe(coffee())
                                      |
                                     ...
                                      |
                                      V
                 _____________________________________________
                 |               |   . . .   |               |
                 |               |   . . .   |               |
                 V               V           V               V
.pipe(replace("a", "b"))    .pipe(replace("a", "c"))     .pipe(replace("a", "y"))
                 |               |           |               |
                 |               |           |               |
                 V               V           V               V
.pipe(gulp.dest("./b"))     .pipe(gulp.dest("./c"))      .pipe(gulp.dest("./y"))
```

Anyone have ideas how to?